# How to calculate category has how many products that related ? (n-th deep relationship)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have table `category` like this:

```
id   name   parent
1    A      0
2    B-1    1
3    B-2    1
4    C-1    2
5    C-2    3
```

In model `Category`

```
public function subCategories()
{
   return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent')->with('subCategories');
}
```

`Note:` Category A has 2 subcategories (B-1, B-2) `1st-level`

B-1 has a subcategory is C-1 `2nd-level`

B-2 has a subcategory is C-2 `3rd-level`

`Only` category is at `3rd-level` has relationship with `product`

Example:

- Category C-1 has 3 products
- Category C-2 has 5 products

How to calculate category has how many products that related ?

`Expected`

- Category A : 8 products (2 sub B-1, B-2)
- Category B-1: 3 products (C-1)
- Category B-2: 5 products (C-2)
- Category C-1: 3 products
- Category C-2: 5 products

I'm pulling my hair out this problem . Any ideas will be also respected . Thanks for all !

Comment: There are two ways, 
High memory and process way but easy,
Low memory and process way but hard.

Easy way: you can use recursive function.
Hard way: write complex sql query.

Comment: In your subCategories() relation, maybe you can do `return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent')->with('subCategories')->count();` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try This in your category model

```
return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent')->with('subCategories')->count();
```

Comment: No , I want to count ```product``` that related to category, not ```subcategories```